# Issues with Spring Basic Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am very new to Spring Security. I want to implement the basic authentication on top of current security mechanism. I have created the configuration as below in security-context.xml.

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/test/info/**">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager id="basicAuthentication">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

It works fine if I don't have any other security configuration. But If I add the below configuration the one which I mentioned above will be overridden. It also calls the class com.aws.web.service.AwsUserDetailsService.

```
<authentication-manager id="authMgr">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="**userDetailsService**">     
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Can any one please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You are overriding the previously declared authentication provider and using wildchar in `**userDetailsService**"` will pick up the first class that it will find in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by giving authentication-manager-ref.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/test/info/**" authentication-manager-ref="basicAuthentication">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager id="basicAuthentication">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```